# how to transfer large data between mongodb dabase realtime

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Now I transfer data with python code:

```
for k in length:
    db[collection].find().limit(step).skip(k * step) # step is 800 in my case
```

Tried more than 2 processing to transfer data from remote mongodb server, but speed didn't increase much. Cpu consuming always kept 103-130% (monitor by glances, 2 core). The machine with limited resource (less than 100G disk) is producing large data in the same time, so I couldn't pause it and transfer data with export and import.

The logs shows below.It cost more than 1 second for one query from Mongodb. So is there any possible to increase the speed?

```
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:48,345 4961 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:96 9125
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:48,345 4961 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:97 process1
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:48,985 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:96 3378
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:48,985 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:97 process2
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:51,919 4955 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:137 sleeping
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:54,984 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:96 3379
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:54,985 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:97 process2
INFO 2017-11-16 03:22:56,926 4955 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:137 sleeping
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:01,932 4955 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:137 sleeping
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:02,361 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:96 3380
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:02,363 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:97 process2
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:02,643 4961 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:96 9126
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:02,644 4961 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:97 process1
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:06,938 4955 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:137 sleeping
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:09,479 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:96 3381
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:09,480 4965 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:97 process2
INFO 2017-11-16 03:23:11,944 4955 140669104162560  consumer_mongodb.py:137 sleeping
```

Comment: why can't you just export and do import

Comment: @AmitP The remote machine (limited resource, less than 100G hardware) is producing large data in the same time, so I couldn't  pause it and transfer the data.

Comment: Using `skip` and `limit` are not exactly your "best friends" here, so a "ranged query" possibly going from the last `_id` of a previous `limit` would perform much better than `skip` here. You don't actually share how you are "writing" on the process and can possibly add "Bulk" inserts/updates depending on what you are doing, but again you really don't share that at all. You can also "pipe" the `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` without creating intermediate "files", and there is a `--limit` option there as well.  So you could explain what you are doing a little better than you have.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your reply.To reduce the complexity, the producer insert data collection by collection. Say, The total number of items could exceed billions. So once a collection is done, I transfer the data to local data warehouse.

Comment: Simple sentences are not really helping your case. You need to edit your question and clarify. Include some sample of the code to show what you are doing, etc. Your current two lines and a list from a log don't explain enough for anyone to give you a meaningful answer. So your question needs fixing is the overall point of the comment and what we are expecting here.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your remind, almost done with mongodump. It's better than mongoexport for keeping the same data type.